# 2 sql query for 1 report source vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, odbc

How to put 2 sql query for 1 report source? i tried using this code but insted of showing two tables, there is no data that is showing.

```
    soa.Show()
    Dim objcr As New receipt


    Dim conn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={" + var.driver + "};server=" + var.server + ";database=" + var.database + ";uid=" + var.uid + ";password=" + var.password + "; port=" + var.port + ""
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("select * from lguset", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da1 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("select * from land where landID = '17'", conn)
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    ds.Tables.Add(dt1)


    objcr.SetDataSource(ds)

    soa.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objcr
    soa.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: :What is the type of `receipt`?

Comment: sorry for that, receipt is the rpt file. receipt.rpt

Comment: Is the form showing? So, a white page on top of the report window you designed? Or is there no sign of a report loading at all?